# Windows 2012 server End of support - Azure

Tags: migration, windows-server-2012

I have 5 to 6 servers currently running on Windows 2012 Server inside my Azure Environment. So as we know, Microsoft will end the support for the 2012 Servers on October 2023. We had thought of proceeding with the clean installation of the new 2019/2022 Windows Servers depending upon the applications and requirements but not the in-place upgrade method. I was really trying very hard to find any documentations or any references for my requirement.

Below are my requirements

1. Create the new VMs with the 2019/2022 Windows Server in my Azure using the Terraform as IaC.
2. Transfer data from the 2012 to 2019/2022 server using Robocopy.

So I need to know if robocopy is a reliable way and what other factors should I consider ion my mind after creating the new VM using Terraform and transferring the files using robocopy.